# Cross-origin CSRF token check fails

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, cross-domain, csrf

I have website `www.example.com` which loads iframe from `www.another.com`. The page being loaded contains a HTML and JS which triggers an AJAX call to self (`www.another.com`). Both of these sites are behind HTTPS.

The iframe loads perfectly fine, the script is executing, BUT, when I click submit (which is part of iframe), I get that `www.another.com` rejected my request due to invalid CSRF token. The form within iframe does contain a `token` field, which has a value (some hash).

The ajax call works fine when I go directly to `www.another.com`.

From what I can grasp so far when ajax call arrives at the server it does not have session started, so it fails to find a token to match.

I use `Symfony 4.4` with `NelmioCorsBundle` to ensure proper CORS. The config looks like this:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        origin_regex: false
        allow_origin: ['https://www.example.com','https://www.another.com']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST']
        allow_headers: ['Origin','Referer']
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 3600
```

Failing ajax request has a following headers:
[image]

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

The domain `www.another.com` was sending `Cookie` header with `SameSite=lax`. That means that those cookies are not to be included unless top-level navigation is initiated. In the case of `iframe` AJAX call, that just won't cut it.

A workaround for this is to disable `SameSite` in `framework.yml`.

```
session:
        cookie_samesite: null <--- THIS
```

I am well aware of potential security ramifications, but:

- the AJAX `POST` endpoint is protected by CSRF token,
- Both of these sites are HTTPS

... so I guess I am going to be fine. Am I?

I am really looking forward to hearing if there is a more serious problem than the one I outlined above :)

Another matter I wanted to point out is how my CORS configuration was not really irrelevant. All of my requests are "simple" ones, and thus do not trigger preflight requests.